# Deleting an Object Entry with delete in Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, strict

I have a vue project where I have to submit the form entries to api endpoint. Unfortunately any empty fields that are submitted throw an error on the server. So I came up with a .filter like method for the form object as follows:

```
Object.entries(formValues).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value === "") {
          delete key;
        }
      });
```

The object is:

```
form: {
        searchTerm: "",
        mediaType: "",
        yearStart: "",
        yearEnd: ""
      }
```

I did not know the delete command was prevented on local variables in strict mode which is being applied by WebPack. Is there a way to delete the Object entry? Have not seen this scenario answered on different sites.

Comment: would setting the value to undefined meet your needs?

Comment: Sorry I tried that and server rejected it. I need any empty fields to be deleted like .filter would do on an array. So easy if was an array.

Comment: You have to `delete formValues[key];` — your `delete` statement as written would mean that you want to delete the parameter, which is not allowed in strict mode. You can still delete object properties however.

Comment: Thank you. I was using dot notation. I forgot cant use variable in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the object explicitly in order to remove attributes/properties from an object:

```
Object.entries(formValues).forEach([key, value] => {
  if (value === "") {
    delete formValues[key];
  }
});
```